# Smooth change of padding / margin of sticky header and page content while scrolling the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, transition

With some help I've managed to create a header which stays on top of the page when page is scrolling with a smooth change of its padding (please note that over a header there is another element) which disappear when scrolling. 
The issue I have is the #wrapper underneath a header changes its margin rapidly and does not follow the transition of header. Generally speaking I want the #wrapper to smoothly follow the decreasing header with a similar transition. 
Here is what I have so far.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/agz9Ljkj/3/)

```js
$(function() {
  var elem = $('header'),
    wrapperElem = $('#wrapper'),
    elemTop = elem.offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    elem.toggleClass('navfixed', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
    wrapperElem.toggleClass('wrapperBelow', $(window).scrollTop() > elemTop);
  }).scroll();
});
```

```css
#ontop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 60px 0;
  transition: padding 0.5s linear;
}
#wrapper {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 5000px;
}
.navfixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 120px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.wrapperBelow {
  margin-top: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ontop">something</div>
<header>navigation</header>
<div id="wrapper">1
  <br/>2
  <br/>3
  <br/>4
  <br/>5
  <br/>6
  <br/>7
  <br/>8
  <br/>9
  <br/>10
  <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a keyframe animation (using jQuery isn't guaranteed to be sync with CSS) :

```
@-webkit-keyframes wrappermargin {
  from {margin-top: 140px;}
  to {margin-top: 42px;}
}

@keyframes wrappermargin {
  from {margin-top: 140px;}
  to {margin-top: 42px;}
}

.wrapperBelow {
  margin-top: 42px;
  -webkit-animation: wrappermargin 0.5s linear;
  animation: wrappermargin 0.5s linear;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvmGaQ?editors=011)

You may notice the animation itself works well but the margin looks off when compared across browsers, the current amount only seems to fit Firefox well (that's a separate issue though)...

Edit - after looking into this, it seems unrelated to the question itself. Neither does it have anything to do with the margins being interpreted differently like mentioned above. It is simply because of the fact that each browser scrolls the page down a different amount when a mousewheel is fired...

Comment: This is much more elegant, just a caveat to the OP; CSS animations are not supported in IE 9 and earlier.

Comment: Cheers, you are correct of course about the limited support. Doing a feature test and falling back on a jQuery animation altogether would probably be the complete solution (I know I do the same when using `requestAnimationFrame` which has the same limitation).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the jquery animate function. Your main problem though is that once your header is given a fixed position, it is removed from the flow so that your wrapper is pushing up on the ontop element.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > elemTop){
    wrapperElem.css('padding-top', '10px');//avoid white flashing
    wrapperElem.css('margin-top', '130px');//set to starting point of nav header as it is being removed from the flow
    wrapperElem.animate({'margin-top': '40px'}, 550);
}
else{
    wrapperElem.css('padding-top', '0px');
    wrapperElem.css('margin-top', '0px');
}
```

Here's it working in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agz9Ljkj/6/).